# IntelliJ adds files to git needlessly when i do maven add project on the pom

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

In the .idea folder of the project, files like

```
idea/compiler.xml
```

are created and added to git

Is there any way to make it not do this. As it is i have to do

```
git rm -rf
```

on the files

Comment: Don't you have "Add silently" option enabled in "Settings | Version Control | Confirmation"? Also you could add ".idea" folder to "Settings | Version Control | Ignored Files".

Comment: Addtionally a `.gitignore` file for the project is a good idea to keep this from happening for the whole team.